# InfoPath 2010 People Picker Behaves Differently In Filler and Browser

Tags: infopath, people-picker, forms-services

I created a form in InfoPath 2010 Designer, and then published it to a SharePoint 2010 form library.  This form has compatibility set to "Web Browser Form".  Most people use this form from a Web Browser (via InfoPath Form Services), but a select few use InfoPath 2010 Filler.

My issue is this: when someone uses a people picker control, they see more results in Filler than they do in the Web Browser.  For example, if they enter a partial name in the people picker and click the "Check Names" icon, two results will be returned in the browser, and four will be returned in Filler.

I am looking for guidance on how the two platforms (Form Services and Filler) behave when it comes to a people picker, and see where I need to dig further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2012/07/18/all-you-want-to-know-about-people-picker-in-sharepoint-functionality-configuration-troubleshooting-part-1.aspx) on Microsoft's site about how a People Picker works with SharePoint.  I am still not 100% sure where the differences are happening, but this article will help me explain what is happening in each scenario.